# Reading through text file and adding substrings (python)

Tags: python, matching, substring

im working with this text file

```
Widget1
partA 2
partB 8
partC 4

Widget2
partD 30
partB 92

Widget3
partA 1
partB 1000
partC 500
partD 450

Widget4
partA 49
partC 100
partD 97

Widget5
partA 10
partD 20
```

I want to add all the parts quantities for each widget, so the output would be 
"Widget 1 needs 14 parts
Widget 2 needs 122 parts" etc. Im having trouble tracking the sum of the quantities to their respective widget. thx in advance. Heres what i have so far

```
widgetfile = open("widgets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
i=0
parttotal=0.0
quantities=[]
widgetdict={}
for line in widgetfile:
            if "Widget" in line:
                widget.append(line)
            if "part" in line:
                substring=line.split(" ")
                quantities.append(substring[1])
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show us what you've tried and what problems you ran into and we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: sorry, i've added what i have so far. its 2 lists, the widget names and the overall quantities. idk how to match the quantities to their widget

Comment: All the extra variables make me wonder: Do you need to do anything with those values after you're done adding up the quantities?

Comment: lol i forgot to delete those. you can ignore that :p

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're adding all quantities to one big list, and then can't distinguish what quantity belongs to what widget. Instead, you could just add up the values on the fly, and when you run into the next "Widget" line (or the end of the file), you know you're done with the widget.

Also, I'd recommend using `with` to automatically close the file when you're done:

```
with open("widgets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as widgetfile:
    current_total = 0
    current_widget = None # We don't have a widget yet
    for line in widgetfile:
        if "Widget" in line:
            # Output the current widget here, if there is one
            if current_widget != None:
                print("{} needs {} parts".format(current_widget, current_total))
            # Now store the new widget's name and reset the count
            current_widget = line
            current_total = 0
        elif "part" in line:
            # Take the second part of the line, convert it to a number
            # and add it to the current total
            current_total += int(line.split()[1])
    # The loop is now done, but we haven't printed the last widget yet
    if current_widget != None:
        print("{} needs {} parts".format(current_widget, current_total))
```

Note how we immediately reset the total count after finishing a single widget, and also how we don't even have to keep track of the individual quantities (or at any point of more than one widget).

Comment: haha while i was w8ing for help i was slightly progressing into what you were doing and created a currentwidget variable etc. Thanks for the help! My logic isn't that great but I hope it will be better the more I code.